# Trying to find difference between two different code

Tags: android, android-studio

This :
[image]
And This :
[image]

how these 2 images are different ?

Comment: You can put the code by typing rather than post the sceenshot when the codes are not really long.

Comment: They seem to be the same, this is this Intellij collapsing your code (first image) to make it look smaller

Answer (score 2):

It is not different. The code u showed first is just unexpanded version of your second code. You may collapse it by just clicking (v) -> { highlighted with grey color